# Retrieve xml from MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, xml, encoding

I'm a noob at C++ and MySQL and I only want to retreive a xml file stored as a longblob in MySQL. I did a `SELECT` query to get the content and after I store this content in a xml file with `std::ofstream`. With this i get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?> <AnObject noNamespaceSchemaLocation...
```

instead of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<AnObject noNamespaceSchemaLocation...
```

So I'm missing the end of line (I think \n). I'm not sure that writing the result of a query to a xml file is the proper way of doing it, is there an other way? Maby it could solve my problem.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You're a *nood*?  http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is similar to this question:

- [SQL Server - Storing linebreaks in XML data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522005/sql-server-storing-linebreaks-in-xml-data-type)

And the highest ranked answer says you need to use a `VARCHAR` (or a `TEXT`) data type.

However, this question discusses the best practices of storing XML in a database, and it recommends storing XML outside the database.  (And if you have SQL Server, `FILESTREAM` is full-text searchable.)

- [Best Practices for storing large amounts of XML type data in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474676/best-practices-for-storing-large-amounts-of-xml-type-data-in-sql-server)